# WooCommerce Product Attribute Taxonomies not normal taxonomies anymore?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

Since some WooCommerce updates apparently the WooCommerce Product Attribute Taxonomies aren't listed as normal taxonomies anymore.
The database table `wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` contains the product taxonomy names, that are also listed as product properties.

```php
$attrName = 'floor';
$taxonomyName = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attrName );
var_dump(taxonomy_exists( $taxonomyName ));
=> false
```

In prior WooCommerce versions this worked just fine, `taxonomy_exists` returned `true`.
The `global $wp_taxonomies;` doesn't contain the WooCommerce Product Attributes anymore, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but `wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` table has not been changed since while *(may be since WooCommerce version 3)* and has nothing to do with this problem.

This seems to be a bug like that comes from WordPress `taxonomy_exists()` conditional function, as if you look to `wp_term_taxonomy` related table you will see that the taxonomy `pa_floor` is registered, so the problem comes from WordPress.

Comment: Only inside the `init` hook the `taxonomy_exists()` function returns `true` for that product attribute taxonomy, in `woocommerce_init` and `plugins_loaded` hooks it always returns `false`. It should work in `woocommerce_init`, right? This seems to be a subtle bug introduced into one of the recent WooCommerce releases.

Comment: @strarsis As plugins are loaded after Wordpress is loaded, I am not sure if this comes from Wordpress or WooCommerce. You should report this issue in WooCommerce Github.